# How to open (enter) SettingsFragment or any Fragment on Android (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I am learning Android programing, and I can not figure it out how to open settings fragment when button is clicked.

This fragment is not in the navigation map, so it is not possible to connect them in navigation and to use `findNavController().navigate(actionFromTo)`

As explained on developer guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings

I have created fragment:

```
    class PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
       override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
           setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
       }
    }
```

What I need to write in click listener to enter settings fragment?

Click listener is:

```
binding.buttonSettings.setOnClickListener {
}
```

I have tried with to use code in developers guide:

```
binding.buttonSettings.setOnClickListener {
            val fragmentManager: FragmentManager? = activity?.supportFragmentManager
            fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.preferencesFragment, PreferencesFragment())?.commit()
        }
```

But program crashes when button is pressed, with error:

> No view found for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the content ID you want to replace, therefore you need to pass the current content ID you want to replace
see below code, use android.R.id.content instead of R.id.preferencesFragment

```
binding.buttonSettings.setOnClickListener {
            val fragmentManager: FragmentManager? = activity?.supportFragmentManager
            fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(android.R.id.content, PreferencesFragment())?.commit()
        }
```